# How do i center the Title on React Natives ToolbarAndroid?

Tags: react-native

I am using the ToolbarAndroid where i need to center the Toolbars Title. I coudn´t figure out how this works. With the Styles properties it didn´t work.

This is my code:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
    title={toolbarTitle(this.props.activeTab)}
    titleColor='white'
    style={styles.toolbar}
    actions={toolbarActions(this.props.activeTab)}
    onActionSelected={this._onActionSelected.bind(this)}>
</ToolbarAndroid>
```

Toolbar style:

```
toolbar: { height: 50, backgroundColor: 'grey' }
```

I can render the title properties and other properties depending on which Tab i am (using scrollable-tab-view) but changing the position where my title is placed didn´t work on my approach

Comment: Can you add the code for `styles.toolbar` please?

Comment: toolbar:  {
        height:          50,
        backgroundColor: 'grey'
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design guidelines toolbar title is aligned to the left. There are some hacky ways to do this in java, but it is probably impossible in react native.
If you don't mind android design guidelines I advise you to use custom component instead of ToolbarAndroid.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a custom view inside the toolbar

```
<ToolbarAndroid>
  <View style={styles.title}>
    <Text>Hi there</Text>
  </View>
</ToolbarAndroid>
```

and center its text

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginRight: 28
  }
});
```

A margin was needed to get alignment right.
In some cases I've seen that it was necessary to set an extra style property like `backgroundColor` for the alignment to work.

Comment: What would be the reason for still using a ToolbarAndroid?

Comment: I'd still want to use the default styling (without needing to recreate that in my own view), and the actions may be useful too. (Though it's been a while that I've used it, so I might miss something here.)